# Multidimensional Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

I just started learning C++. I was trying to grasp the syntax for multidimensional arrays and vectors when I started to get fairly confused. I get how to initialize multidimensional arrays. It seems straightforward:  Rows followed by columns. However, vectors are a little more challenging. Do I have to initialize them in the same way or do I create a vector of vectors?

Comment: Vector of vectors (of vectors...).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are able to use C++11, multidimensional arrays and vectors of vectors can be initialized in a similar manner.

```
int a1[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
```

However, there are differences that must be understood to access the elements without running into undefined behavior.

For a multidimensional array, memory for the elements of the array is required to be allocated contiguously. For a vector of vector, the memory for the elements is most likely going to be disjoint.

Memory for `a1`:

```
a1[0][0]    a1[1][0]    a1[2][0]
|           |           |
v           v           v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Memory for `a2` (most likely):

```
a2[0][0]
|
v
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+

a2[1][0]
|
v
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+

a2[2][0]
|
v
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Also, it is possible to defined a vector of vectors in which the number of columns is not same for each row.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9} };
```

In a multidimensional array, the number of columns is guaranteed to be same for each row.

Given the above multidimensional array `a1`, `a1[1][2]` will be a valid element and `a1[2][3]` will be an invalid element. In the case of a vector of vectors, using the above line, `a2[1][2]` is not a valid element and `a2[2][3]` is a valid element.

Comment: Is there a way to make multidimensional vectors (like 3d or more dimensions) more clearer and easier to read?

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamez, when you have a need for such arrays, it's best to encapsulate their usage behind a class. That will make it easier to use the class but the implementation of the class has to deal with the syntactic aspects of arrays. I don't think there's way to get around that.

Answer (score 22):

declare a multidimensional vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> test(4,vector<int>(20));
```

This creates a 2D vector 4 X 20.  Of course since they're vectors that can be changed as needed.  The indexing is the same as an array `test[3][19]`.

Answer (score 6):

For interested readers, Boost has a MultiArray library designed specifically for this problem. It claims to be more efficient than `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` and its interface is C++ STL friendly.

```cpp
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

int main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  boost::multi_array<double, 3>  A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);
 
  // Assignment
  A[0][0][0] = 1.0;

  // Dereference
  std::cout<<A[0][0][0];
  
return 0;
}
```

Read more [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

Comment: For vector, matrix and tensor calculation, checkout Eigen C++ library: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org