# How to declare multi-dimension array with specific size?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I originally declared by array:

```
constexpr auto array_size = 50000000; 
double M[array_size][2][20]= { };
```

However, it will crash during runtime.

I plan to use vector:

I found an example for 2D array:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
```

However, I don't know how to assign the vector size (ex: 50000000 ) to each dimension.

Maybe by 'new' will easier, but I don't know how to declare it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Vectors in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325425/multidimensional-vectors-in-c)

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> M(50000000, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(2, std::vector<double>(20)));`

Comment: If those two inferior dimensions really are fixed, you don't want a vector of vector of vector; you want a std::vector of std::array of std::array. Keep in mind, however, the requirement of contiguous region for such a thing, especially for sizes like what you're looking at. You may be forced to a vector of vector of array.

Comment: The size of array you are allocating is just too much to be held on stack. On my computer `double` is 8 bytes, so the size of `M` would be 16 GB.

Comment: `However, I don't know how to assign the vector size (ex: 50000000 ) to each dimension.` A 3-dimensional Array with 50'000'000 in each direction with double as type, would result in 1yotta-byte... you probably will have a hard time finding RAM...

Comment: @user1810087 that goodness two of those dimensions are fixed and small (2, 20). (actually, all three in this case).

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a run-time array-esque class.
`std::array` is a compile-time array-esque class.

I can only assume it's crashing because 50000000 is an enormous amount of ram to allocate for a single object and I can only assume you are doing this several times.

to resize an `std::vector`, use the `resize( uNewSize )` function member like so:

```
std::vector< int > vecIntegers { 1, 2, 3 }; // size is 3.
vecIntegers.resize( 4 );
vecIntegers[ 3 ] = 4;
for ( auto integer: vecIntegers )
    std::cout << integer << ' ';
```

This program will print `1 2 3 4`.

Multidimensional arrays of `std::vector`'s are done by nesting them like in your question:

`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec3d;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use resize member of std::vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> multivec;

multivec.resize(outersize);
for (int i = 0; i < outersize; ++i)
   multivec[i].resize(midsize);
```

etc for inner loop

or alternatively using a for range loop (after resize)

```
for (auto &vec : multivec) 
   vec.resize(midsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is fixed size, [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is the preferred.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>    

    int main() {             
        using array1d =  std::array<int, 2>;
        using array2d = std::array<array1d, 50>;
        std::array<array2d,5000> a1;  

        std::cout << "size = "<< sizeof(a1);
        return 0;
    }
```

2*20*50000000 = 2GB, program will crash while assigning this dynamic memory.